# Too many changes in repo

Tags: git, atom-editor

I am using the Atom code editor and and familiarizing myself with Git command line (Terminal). However, why do I keep getting "Too many changes - The repository at /Users/me has too many changed files to display in Atom. Ensure that you have set up an appropriate .gitignore file."? I have tried committing a project of mine (simple chatbot service in Python3), but should I instead commit the files in my repository first before moving on to separate projects and the related? What does "Too many changes" mean?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to commit your entire home directory... not a directory containing "a few" project files.

Comment: @ivanivan What would you suggest then? Should I change directory (cd) to my user folder (or whichever I use to store my projects) and then commit the project there?

Answer (score 0):

You have a git repo in your user folder.

Atom refuses to handle situations like that because, when a user has a repo
that’s over tens or hundreds of thousands of files that weren’t being ignored,
Atom would try to look at them all, take up a huge amount of resources, and crash.

You may store your repositories anywhere you want, as long as there’s nothing inside
the repository that isn’t supposed to be a part of it, like the contents of your
user folder.